# Растягивание картинки в блоке

Tags: html, css, изображения

подскажите как можно сделать?

есть картинка большая горизонтальная, она вставляется в блок.

Должно получиться так, что картинка растягивается по родительскому блоку на 100%, а вертикально согласно пропорциям + там где картинки не должно быть должна быть белая пустота.

Пытался стилями сделать(w:100% h:auto), что-то не очень получилось. Кажется  css достаточно будет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

скрин того что хочу увидеть приложил

Comment: `img { max-width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

Картинку перенес в `background`.

Добавил стили:

```
height: 250px;

background-color: inherit;

background-size: 100% auto;

background-image: url(/upload/iblock/5bc/5bc8b08….jpg);

background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-position: center;
```

Проблема решена

Answer (score 0):

> Проблема решена

Проверь-ка эту проблему при вертикальной картинке.
А потом попробуй просто этот стиль:

```
{
  background-position: center;
  background-size:contain;
}
```